# Posting Key-Value pairs with PHP to a ip & port

Tags: php, post, curl

Please don't shoot me or call me names. I want to post something like this to an IP:port and get the response back. So simple a caveman can do it but, looks like this caveman is hit with a large club. Please help

`$url: tcp 127.0.0.1 $port: 500`

```
                 POST Method
                 field1 = Test
                 field2 = Me
                 field3 = Now
```

Response back from server that's it.

Please help or point me to the simplest explanation. Now of course above is not my code I am not that stupid just putting the basic info.

Thanks in advance.